# Trouble with chart scaling and zooming using Chart.js and chartjs-zoom-plugin

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, zooming, pan

I'm trying to add chartjs-zoom-plugin to my project, where's Y axis - is temperature from 0 to 100, and x - axis is a number of channels from 0 to 4200+. Beforehand, sorry for my english.

So, I wrote some code at my project, zooming is working, but while zooming, the x-axis index don't change, and it's very hard to understand the information from my chart.Y-values change according the place i zoom, but x-values don't.

```js
var ctx, config;

// filler data as actual data was not provided in original post
var dotsForXLabel = [0,700,1400,2100,4160,4200];
var filteredTempMas = [30,10,40,90,100,-60];

function buildChart() {
  config = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      "labels": dotsForXLabel,
      "datasets": [{
        "label": "DTS Riga",
        "data": filteredTempMas,
        "fill": false,
        "borderColor": "rgb(192,35,16)",
        "pointRadius": 0.5,
        "pointHoverBackgroundColor": 'red',
        "pointHoverBackgroundColor": 'red',
        "lineTension": 0.1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      // tooltips: {
      //     mode: 'dataset'
      // },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },

          scaleLabel: {
            display: false,
            labelString: 'Метр участка ОВК',
          },

        }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,

          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Температура'
          }
        }]
      },




      plugins: {
        zoom: {
          zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x', // Allow zooming in the x direction
            rangeMin: {
              x: 0 // Min value of the duration option
            },
            rangeMax: {
              x: 100 // Max value of the duration option
            },
            drag: true,
            mode: 'xy',
            speed: 0.7
          }
        },
        pan: {
          enabled: true, // Enable panning
          mode: 'x', // Allow panning in the x direction
          rangeMin: {
            x: 0 // Min value of the delay option
          },
          rangeMax: {
            x: 100 // Max value of the delay option
          }
        },

      }
    }
  });
};

window.resetZoom = function() {
  window.myLine.resetZoom();
};

window.toggleDragMode = function() {
  var chart = window.chart;
  var zoomOptions = config.options.plugins.zoom.zoom;
  zoomOptions.drag = !zoomOptions.drag;
  chart.update();
  document.getElementById('drag-switch').innerText = zoomOptions.drag ? 'Disable drag mode' : 'Enable drag mode';
};

window.onload = function() {
  ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  buildChart();
  //window.myLine = new window.Chart(ctx, config);
};
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.5"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id='canvas' />
  </div>
</body>
```

**Screenshot of actual chart**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The pan options should be placed under options.zoom (same level as options.zoom.zoom).
2. option.zoom.zoom.mode is specified twice - one of them should be removed.
3. rangeMin and rangeMax values only limit the axis range (as min and max values) and have no effect on duration

*In the fixed example below, dragZoom has been disabled to allow for panning when zoomed in.

```js
var ctx, config;

// filler data as actual data was not provided in original post
var dotsForXLabel = [0, 700, 1400, 2100, 4160, 4200];
var filteredTempMas = [30, 10, 40, 90, 100, -60];

function buildChart() {
  config = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      "labels": dotsForXLabel,
      "datasets": [{
        "label": "DTS Riga",
        "data": filteredTempMas,
        "fill": false,
        "borderColor": "rgb(192,35,16)",
        "pointRadius": 0.5,
        "pointHoverBackgroundColor": 'red',
        "pointHoverBackgroundColor": 'red',
        "lineTension": 0.1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      // tooltips: {
      //     mode: 'dataset'
      // },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },

          scaleLabel: {
            display: false,
            labelString: 'Метр участка ОВК',
          },

        }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,

          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Температура'
          }
        }]
      },




      plugins: {
        zoom: {
          zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x', // Allow zooming in the x direction
            rangeMin: {
              x: 0 // 
            },
            rangeMax: {
              x: 4200 //
            },
            //drag: true,
            //mode: 'xy',
            speed: 0.7
          },

          pan: {
            enabled: true, // Enable panning
            mode: 'x', // Allow panning in the x direction
            rangeMin: {
              x: 0 //
            },
            rangeMax: {
              x: 4200 // 
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  });
};

window.onload = function() {
  ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  buildChart();
  //window.myLine = new window.Chart(ctx, config);
};
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.5"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id='canvas' />
  </div>
</body>
```